# Visual Studio Code maven project - how to add a source folder

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I am trying to migrate our maven java projects to Visual Studio from Eclipse.

Our Maven projects have a generated source folder (for our soap service schema classes) in src/main/generated folder (with appropriate build-helper-maven-plugin config in the POM)

In eclipse, I can manually right click on the module and "add source folder" to tell eclipse about the folder.

I can't seem to find such an option in the maven plugin for VSCode which is causing hundreds of "The import xxx cannot be resolved" errors

How can I resolve this? We are being pushed to move away from eclipse and into visual studio but I cannot do so at the moment until I can resolve this issue.

If it helps, here's the relevant POM config:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/generated</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute></execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

Comment: The most important thing in Maven is to follow conventions. `src/main/generated` is not convention. The default is to generate code into `target/generated...` That's a thing I would strongly recommend to change...afterwards I bet migration will be easier...

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem though, it's still an additional source folder that vsc can't find. I could generate it into the normal src/main/java but that would pollute our service code there and I'd have to reconfigure our code quality tools to exclude scanning the new location - I'd rather not do that unless I am forced to.

Comment: Use the convention and let the generation into `target/` directory not into `src/` directory. No build-helper etc. needed...The default of cxf is: `<sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>`...so convention is to use that...

Comment: Will this comment help your case: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/177#issuecomment-673333479 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: In this menu, which is at the bottom left of your screen, open Maven, find the project you are working on.]

In this menu, which is at the bottom left of your screen, open Maven, find the project you are working on, and right click. You will see an option that says custom. Select that. Then enter in the Command platte that shows up at the top: "generate-source"